# Pronunciation of the word 'tablet'

Tags: pronunciation

The pronunciation of the word 'tablet' as I found in Oxford dictionary is: [ˈtæblət]
While Google say this: ˈtablɪt.
Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, both of these pronunciations come from Oxford Dictionaries. The first one (ˈtæblət) comes from the [US page](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/tablet) and the other one (ˈtablɪt) comes from [the page that has British pronunciations](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tablet).

Which one you use depends on which dialect you're using.

For American English (my dialect), I also think that /tæblɪt/ is an acceptable pronunciation, where the last syllable can be pronounced the same way as the word "lit".

Comment: But I found this [ˈtæblət] as AmE in Oxford. [https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tablet?q=tablet]

Comment: That is correct. Laurel says the same, the /ə/ pronunciation is American. But they also, correctly, note that there is individual variation. There is also contextual variation, as unstressed vowels tend to become schwa when speaking quickly or casually.

Answer (score 0):

Either is acceptable. This is part of a more general phenomenon: it's not essential to distinguish [ɪ] from [ə] before a consonant in a fully unstressed syllable. Many native speakers don't make this distinction; I think it's more common in British English than in American English, but even British English speakers don't all show the exact same patterns of usage.

The use of "æ" vs. "a" is simply a difference in transcription conventions. They represent the same vowel "phoneme".